# Missing "caption" field in Instagram Graph API response

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

When I hover the caption fields on **Graph API Explorer** this message appears: "Field is empty or disallowed by the access token"

Is this is bug or something else? This error appear after the 2024-01-05. Before the 2024-01-05 I was able to read caption fields.

Here is access permissions:

```
business_management, instagram_basic, pages_show_list, instagram_manage_insights, pages_read_engagement
```

request url:
`[ID]/stories?fields=id,comments_count,like_count,media_product_type,media_type,media_url,timestamp,caption`

response:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "...",
      "comments_count": 0,
      "like_count": 0,
      "media_product_type": "STORY",
      "media_type": "VIDEO",
      "timestamp": "2024-01-16T16:35:15+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "...",
      "comments_count": 0,
      "like_count": 0,
      "media_product_type": "STORY",
      "media_type": "IMAGE",
      "media_url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/...",
      "timestamp": "2024-01-16T11:42:38+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "...",
      "comments_count": 0,
      "like_count": 0,
      "media_product_type": "STORY",
      "media_type": "IMAGE",
      "media_url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t51...",
      "timestamp": "2024-01-16T11:41:07+0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "...",
      "comments_count": 0,
      "like_count": 0,
      "media_product_type": "STORY",
      "media_type": "VIDEO",
      "media_url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/o1/...",
      "timestamp": "2024-01-16T10:44:49+0000"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "...",
      "after": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Instagram Graph API since 2022. Since 2024-01-05 some users media data has no "caption" fields on story. I try to change API usage on my system but I could not solve.